# ArrayList<String> sorting issue

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having a weird ArrayList issue. When i use the below code to populate List in a hard-coded values, it works fine.

```
    ProfileCreds = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProfileCreds.add(0,"user");
    ProfileCreds.add(1,"password");
    ProfileCreds.add(2,"host");
    ProfileCreds.add(3,"port");

    Log.d("user", ProfileCreds.get(0));
    Log.d("pass", ProfileCreds.get(1));
    Log.d("host", ProfileCreds.get(2));
    Log.d("port", ProfileCreds.get(3));

    //I get correct order as it should be
```

But when i populate the same ArrayList using input from user, i observe that the list indexes are not in the order as they were when added. The code is pretty much the same. Only hardcoded strings are replaced with view inputs.

```
    ProfileCreds = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProfileCreds.add(0,SSHUser.getText().toString());
    ProfileCreds.add(1,SSHPassword.getText().toString());
    ProfileCreds.add(2,SSHServer.getText().toString());
    ProfileCreds.add(3,SSHPort.getText().toString());

    Log.d("user", ProfileCreds.get(0));
    Log.d("pass", ProfileCreds.get(1));
    Log.d("host", ProfileCreds.get(2));
    Log.d("port", ProfileCreds.get(3));

    //Output i get
    user : [value of host]
    pass : [value of pass]
    host : [value of user]  
    port : [value of port]
```

I am not using the list anywhere and there is no sorting applied. Also, i am doing all this inside an `onClick` handler inside an activity and the views are all of type `EditText`.

Comment: have you checked that `SSHUser.getText().toString()` contains the user and not the host string?

Comment: @wero `SSHUser.getText().toString()` does contain the incorrect value. And that is the problem. But i have checked the views and there does not seem to be incorrect refrences/id.

Comment: so its not about that the list gets resorted, but that SSHUser and and SSHServer contain the wrong values. Are these textfields in the GUI?

Comment: Wrong order in ArrayList is impossible. The error somwhere in a code, not listed above; or in SSHUser SSHPassword SSHServer SSHPort field names (probably they are messed)

Answer (score 0):

Try using just `ProfileCreds.add(String)` instead of `ProfileCreds.add(int, String)`

```
ProfileCreds.add(SSHUser.getText().toString());
ProfileCreds.add(SSHPassword.getText().toString());
ProfileCreds.add(SSHServer.getText().toString());
ProfileCreds.add(SSHPort.getText().toString());
```

Comment: It produces the same result. I did that before and i just wanted to make sure indexes have right value so used other construct.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the Log methods take a tag string as a first argument. Following best practices, you would define a final static string TAG to have one value, such as the name of your app or your class. The call to your Log method would then look like:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAppName";

    private void someMethod() {
        Log.d(TAG, "user=" + ProfileCreds.get(0));
    }

}
```